# CodenameOne: Is it possible to define 'Views' for different usergroups of the app?

Tags: mobile, view, codenameone

I am currently planning to develop an app using *CodenameOne* and I was wondering if if was possible to define some **database like views** onto an app, so that **different users see different parts of the app**?

I am talking about an application, that is part of a **project structure**, that is **made up of different modules**, which need to be bought **separately**, but should all be integrated into the same app. As some kind of advertising strategie, the unbought parts should be displayed, but have no functionality.

Another question, closely related to this would be how to let different people use different GUIS of the same app?

Example: There is a master and a worker.

Master has these menus:

```
- show all machines
- show available teams
- send message to team x
```

Worker has these menus:

```
- show my machine
- show my team
- send message to master
```

If the master reassignes a team, the team members menu's contents would just change accordingly, without the app itself changing.

if a worker gets assigned as master, the server would send something like `you are now the master` and the view would change to the masters view (still in the same app)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no builtin support for something like that if I understand you correctly. You could probably use a set of permissions system and if statements to achieve that but there is no system where you can explicitly say "this module is only visible to that user".

Comment: When I was thinking further about this, I came to a possiblity:

What if I had a Login-Screen and after someone logged in, the server would look up its rights and send instructions to the mobile, that makes it build its user-specific, dynamic GUI? What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you might be needing is just to build those views dynamically. If the application logic says that a certain user is the master - then you build a master-like view for that user otherwise you create simple worker view. Regarding the assignation (which master rules a worker), it is just the basic one-to-many relationship paradigm.

Tips on building your views dynamically with GUI + Code :

```
public UserViewBuilder extends UIBuilder { 
    private Resource res; 
    private Container view;
    //User is the parent class of both Worker and Master
    private User user;
    ...
    public UserView(Resource res){
         this.res = res;
    }
    private void init(boolean isMasterView){
        //where you initialize all the component of your view
    }
    ...
    public Container viewSelector(boolean isUserMaster){
         if(isUserMaster){
              //getting data for a master-user, just throwing ideas
              this.user = Data.fetchYourMasterData();
              //getting the design from GUI
              this.view =this.createContainer(res,"ContainerDesignForMaster");
              //putting the necessary data into the design
              this.init(isUserMaster);
           }
           else {
              //getting data for a worker-user, just throwing ideas
              this.user = Data.fetchYourWorkerData();
              //getting the design from GUI
              this.view =this.createContainer(res,"ContainerDesignForWorker");
              //putting the necessary data into the design
              this.init(isUserMaster);
            }
    }
    ...
}
```

Using that architecture approach you will create the design for master and worker with the GUI builder - then you will code the view selection logic.

(Let me know if you need a working sample netbeans project for better understanding)

Comment: This is a good answer that will work and some people have picked that approach. It relies on using the old UI Builder which is something we are moving away from. Its also a bit harder to manage that as it would require binding the event handling manually.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I would use this kind of concept, would it be possible to not only handle different views dynamically, but also allow users to have multiple views at once? If `master(machine1)` gets assigned to also be `master(machine2)` because the original master is ill?